# Detecting Hololens in the browser

Tags: user-agent, hololens

How do you detect if a user is visiting your website using a Hololens?

The user-agent of the hololens seems to be equal to the one used by Edge.

Comment: Were you able to find a reliable solution for this problem? I'm currently in need of a solution for this myself.

Comment: @JoshuaSutherland We checked for the height and width of the window(it  stayed the same even if you resized the window), and we checked if it is an Edge browser.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look the image attached showing a Hololens with a user-agent, the Edge build number is higher than the publicly released version of Edge for Windows 10 desktop.

Ideally feature detection would be preferred, or detect on `navigator.prototype.platform == "Windows.Holographic"` would be best, but this seems to be the best way to detect for it.

[image: User-Agent example from Hololens Edge]

Comment: We noticed this too, however this is not a very reliable way to detect a hololens. This way we have to continuously update the hololens check. Currently we detect the hololens using the window size(resolution) in combination with an Edge browser check. Even if you resize the browser window the resolution stays the same.

Comment: I'm curious about why you want to know it's a HoloLens. Edge is Edge, regardless of the device, right?  I am not trying to be flippant, I am curious if there is something you can do inside the browser that is HoloLens specific.

Comment: @JesseMcCulloch - For example, in hololens you might want much bigger fonts for everything on the page compared to a monitor of the same resoution.

Comment: @JesseMcCulloch I've been working with the Hololens, in particular with Javascript and Blob handling, and have noticed some serious discrepancies between how Edge on Windows and Edge on the Hololens will handle files. Not everything seems to be supported as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

So far the Edge user agent on Hololens was not containing "Win64; x64".
Since Edge version 112.0.1722.58 (may be earlier) it does, and now the user agents of Edge on Windows Desktop and Edge in Hololens are exactly the same (despite the version numbers).

This is painful because detecting Hololens platform in Edge for Hololens allowed me to trigger an Hololens application launch through custom URL scheme.

By the way `navigator.prototype.platform` does not exists, it's `navigator.platform`, and nowadays it's equal to "Win32" for both. Also `navigator.platform` is deprecated while the new API `navigator.userAgentData.platform` is equal to "Windows" for both platforms.

**EDIT:**

Apparently there is a `sec-ch-ua-platform-version` HTTP header which has a match with the Windows "Settings > System > About > Edition" and version.
`platformVersion` for Windows are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/how-to-detect-win11#detecting-specific-windows-versions).

Apparently `platformVersion` equals 12.0.0 for "Windows Holographic for Business" which is the current Hololens 2 Windows edition.
I do not know about Hololens 1 but since platformVersion 11 is not documented it may be 11.0.0.

More details on
User Agent Client hints in [Edge doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/how-to-detect-win11#sample-code-for-detecting-windows-11) and [Mozilla doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/how-to-detect-win11#sample-code-for-detecting-windows-11).

Comment: this is not working anymore, platformVersion is now 15.0.0 as it is for the latest Windows 11 version running on a non hololens environment